# Dynamic Opacity not changing when component rerenders in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, opacity, touchableopacity

I'm starting to learn React Native, and for my project I created a simple Button component to reuse in my project. I set the opacity value dynamically according to the variable 'disabled', however, the look of the button is not changing with the value of the opacity variable. I searched around and I have not found an explanation..
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my source code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

//TODO: arrumar o problema com a opacidade
export default function Button({text, onPress, style, disabled, textStyle}) {
    let opacity = disabled === true ? 0.5 : 1
    // console.log('opacity', opacity)
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[defaultStyles.button, style, {opacity: opacity}]} 
            disabled={disabled}>
            <Text style={[defaultStyles.text, textStyle]}>{text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )

}

const defaultStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        margin: 15,
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10
    },
})

Button.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string,
    onPress: PropTypes.func,
    style: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.array,
        PropTypes.object
    ]),
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    textStyle: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.array,
        PropTypes.object
    ])
}
```

EDIT: 
Here is the code the calls the button

```
class NewDeck extends Component {

    state={
        title: null
    }

    submit = () => {
        const { add, goBack } = this.props
        let deck = {...this.state}
        if(!deck['deckId']){
            deck['deckId'] = Date.now()
            deck['logs'] = []
        }

        !deck['cardsId'] && (deck['cardsId'] = [])

        add(deck).then(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Deck', {deckId: deck.deckId, title: deck.title})
            this.setState({title: null})
            }
        )
    }

    render(){
        const disabled = this.state.title === null || this.state.title.length === 0
        return (
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                <Text style={textStyles.title2}>Whats the title of your deck?</Text>
                    <TextInput editable={true} style={[styles.input, textStyles.body]}
                    placeholder='Type title here'
                    maxLength={25}
                    value={this.state.title}
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.setState({title: text})
                    }}
                    />
                <Button
                    onPress={this.submit}
                    text='Submit'
                    style={{backgroundColor: colors.pink}}
                    textStyle={textStyles.body}
                    disabled={!this.state.title} 
                />
              </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            )
    }
}
```

The disabled variable is true if the title of the newDeck component is empty or null. When this variable is true, the opacity of the button should be only 0.5. When the value goes to false, then the opacity changes to 1 again. If I log the value of the opacity in the component, I can see it going from 0.5 to 1, but the look of the component doesn't change.

Comment: Nothing in your code can control dynamic rendering. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Just a buttom that the opacity changes if the disabled variable is true.

Comment: Let us see how you are using that button

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I put more information!

Comment: can you put the opacity inside the TouchableOpacity text and see if it changes

Comment: @monssef Just did it and it does. Is Style not a dynamic thing?

Comment: style should change on a re-render, unless the diffing algo things nothing changed on your component

Comment: i was able to reproduce you problem

Answer (score 42, accepted):

not sure if it's a bug on the **TouchableOpacity** component, but the opacity won't update on a re-render until the component is clicked

to fix your problem just wrap the content of the touchable in a **View** and apply the **opacity** to the view instead of the touchable

```
export default function Button({text, onPress, style, disabled, textStyle}) {
    const opacity = disabled === true ? 0.5 : 1
    // console.log('opacity', opacity)
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} disabled={disabled} 
          style={[defaultStyles.button, style]}>
          <View style={{opacity}}>
            <Text style={[defaultStyles.text, textStyle]}>{text}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )

}
```

Comment: my pleasure, please make sure to mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: You save my life. Thanks

Comment: update opacity without click on component was worked with your workaround but still opacity has been updated with some delay. is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: don't apply opacity to the touchable only the view

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I also changed the `disabled` prop together with the opacity.

I guess the issue is that the opacity in `TouchableOpacity` is an `Animated.Value` that overrides the value in the `style` prop and doesn't change, when the `style` prop changes...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion correct solution is to use [setOpacityTo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html#setopacityto) method.

In your `render`:

```
render() {
  const opacityValue = this.props.disabled ? 0.5 : 1;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={{ opacity: opacityValue }} ref={(btn) => { this.btn = btn; }} onPress={this.onPress}>
      <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

And next you can use `setOpacityTo` method in `componentDidUpdate` on `disabled` props change:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { disabled } = this.props;
    if (disabled !== prevProps.disabled) {
      const opacityValue = disabled ? 0.5 : 1;
      this.btn.setOpacityTo(opacityValue);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **React Native version 0.63** onwards then Pressable is more elegant solution to go with and its Opacity change works as expected.

```
<Pressable
    style={{
       opacity: item.isSelected ? 0.5 : 1
    }}>
       //Your button content goes here
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it's a weird behavior, just a work around add a View component with the desired styling inside the TouchableOpacity component like this :

```
     <TouchableOpacity >
      {/* this view is just because opacity doesn't work dynamically on touchable opacity */}
      <View style={{opacity : (loading)? 0.5 : 1 }}>

      <Text>Your text here</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```