# React Native setState not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, render

Expected behaviour of this component is like this: I press it, selectedOpacity() function is called, state is updated so it now renders with opacity=1.

But for some reason, after calling this.setState, it is not being re-rendered. I have to click this component again to make it re-render and apply changes of opacity from state.

```
export default class Category extends Component {

state = {
  opacity: 0.5
}

selectedOpacity() {
  // some stuff
  this.setState({opacity: 1})
}

render() {
 return(
  <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, {opacity: this.state.opacity}]} onPress={() => {
    this.selectedOpacity();
  }}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 )
}
```

Comment: missing `constructor()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Opacity not changing when component rerenders in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979866/dynamic-opacity-not-changing-when-component-rerenders-in-react-native)

Comment: So it appears that using TouchableOpacity there is bugged in this scenario, any ideas though to avoid this bugg and still use TouchableOpacity?

Answer (score 0):

Change **selectedOpacity** to arrow function:

```
selectedOpacity = () => {
  this.setState({opacity: 1})
}
```

Then:

```
onPress={this.selectedOpacity}
```

**Edit**: The react documentation says its experimental and the syntax is called [public class field syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: this would be undefined in arrow functions AFAIK if not bound.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan Have you ever tried that before? I think you're totally wrong

Comment: Yes ofcourse. "An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords." Ref: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan Seriously? A lot of people around the world are using arrow function instead of binding(ES6). Please read this article https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I just read that the syntax you posted should work. But it says its experimental. Its called [public class field syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Could you please edit the answer and include this information for posterity and to remove the downvote.

Comment: Not anymore. Like I said, people are almost using it instead of binding

Comment: AFAIK An experimental feature is one where the design is not finalized. The feature is available for users to test and provide feedback.

Comment: You can google it. I don't want to argue with you. We can end of discussion here.

Comment: Sure man. It's just a constructive talk, that's all. Don't take offense.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is binding of selectedOpacity(), else `this` would be undefined in it AFAIK.

Also better move the assignment of state to a constructor().

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.selectedOpacity = this.selectedOpacity.bind(this);
}
```

Also change to the following because [creating an arrow function inside render affects performance](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36).

```
onPress={this.selectedOpacity}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try change onpress to
`onPress={() => this.selectedOpacity()}`

Comment: Nothing changes, still first click is not updating render

Comment: @leighton `onPress={() => this.selectedOpacity()}` is same as `onPress={this.selectedOpacity}`

Comment: Yeah, sorry - my bad